# Wordpress remove whitespace from users input tel link

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry if I am a PHP noob...

I am trying to remove the whitespace from a user's input so that the "tel link" doesn't have any spaces within it.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="nt-menu-phone-number">

                <?php

                if( !empty ($nt_theme_options['menu_style1_number'])) { ?>

                    <a href="tel:<?php echo esc_html($nt_theme_options['menu_style1_number']); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($nt_theme_options['menu_style1_number']); ?></a>

                <?php } ?>

</div>
```

How do I go about removing the whitespace? I have tried putting the trim() function around it but no luck.

Any helps greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the white spaces. I have not got any white spaces from this code.. I am getting the output as `<a href="tel:9874563210">9874563210</a>` if i assume the number as 9874563210

Comment: Hi Naresh, if a users input is say 08 1234 5678 the actual link needs to be tel:12345678, and I can't seem to remove the whitespace within the actual link itself.

Comment: Added my rectified output below. Refer to it @Notorious

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, exactly what I needed to do, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow u the code that i have given below.

To remove all white spaces in the sting, use [preg_replace();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

> Output: 0812345678

```
<?php 
$nt_theme_options['menu_style1_number'] = '08 1234 5678';
?>
<div class="nt-menu-phone-number">
<?php
if( !empty ($nt_theme_options['menu_style1_number'])) { ?>
<a href="tel:<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$nt_theme_options['menu_style1_number']); ?>"><?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$nt_theme_options['menu_style1_number']); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much Naresh I appreciate it :)

Comment: If so you would have marked the answer as useful right. Pls do it @Notorious. Have fun..

Comment: Just checked as the right answer (new to stackoverflow) - thanks! : )